# Unable to download any apps whatsoever from google play store

Tags: google-play-store

Recently I found an issue with downloading apps from the play store. I am able to select the install button, and it goes to the loading bar without issue, but stays in that indefinitely. I left my phone overnight for several hours, to wake and find that an app has yet to install. It does not show a progress bar, but instead consistently says it is “downloading”. I am running Nougat on an Asus ZenFone Deluxe. There are no current patches or updates issued as of today that I write this post, so I cannot download a new update and hope that this is some bug that will be fixed. I have tried force closing the app, changing networks and connecting through wi fi and cellular, as well as clearing the cache for the google play app. I checked that the phone connected to the internet through using the web browser, which worked perfectly fine.

Addition 1: As suggested by a comment, I cleared my data for Google Play as well. Had no effect.

Comment: Cleared the data, still hasn’t helped :(

Comment: Restarted your phone?

Comment: Yep, I did that too

Comment: I’ve restarted it several times. Should I just do a factory reset? Everything is backed up to the cloud anyways, and I don’t really have any documents on it or anything that I couldn’t afford to lose.

Comment: you can try downloading apps from a browser on play stores website, otherwise i can't think of a suggestion other than factory reset

Comment: Try uninstalling all updates of play store and connect to Internet for updation and see if that helps

Comment: Tried that, still hasn’t worked ;(

Comment: Ok. Now it works....maybe networks were the issue? All the networks I use have Been spotty.